# Using sub-menus with Tabulator, better highlighting and use mouseover, not click event

Tags: tabulator

I'm using the nested menu feature (https://tabulator.info/docs/5.5/menu#overview-nested) and I'd like to make the following improvements:

1. for sub-menus to show with a mouseover, not a click
2. when selecting an item that shows a submenu, changing the background of that menu item so it's clear where the submenu comes from

I looked at the documentation and this functionality does not seem to be available.